# How to generate maps with different section highlighted each time with a for loop?

Tags: r, for-loop, dictionary

I would like to generate a set of maps in R with all of them having the same background (a focus on Europe) BUT each of them having one EU country highlighted in another color. And I can't seem to figure out how to write the for loop to get that...

Here is my code:

```
require(rgdal)

setwd(...) #where I have my GIS shapefile
world <- readOGR(dsn = ".", layer = "TM_WORLD_BORDERS-0.2")

#Subset European countries

#List of "european" countries + shapefile
europe <- c("Russia", "Isle of Man", "Channel Islands", "Faroe Islands", 
            "France", "Denmark", "Iceland", "Germany", "Romania", "Poland", "Portugal", 
            "United Kingdom", "Spain", "Sweden", "Lithuania", "Ireland", "Italy", 
            "Netherlands", "Norway", "Ukraine", "Latvia", "Estonia", "Finland", 
            "Bulgaria", "Belgium", "Montenegro", "Serbia and Montenegro", "Slovenia",
            "Albania", "Greece", "Croatia", "Malta")
europe <- subset(world, NAME %in% europe)

#List of countries in the EU + shapefile
EU <- c("Isle of Man", "Channel Islands", "Faroe Islands", "France",
        "Denmark", "Germany", "Romania", "Poland", "Portugal", "Spain", "Sweden",
        "Lithuania", "Ireland", "Italy", "Netherlands", "Ukraine", "Latvia", "Estonia",
        "Finland", "Bulgaria", "Belgium", "Montenegro", "Serbia and Montenegro",
        "Slovenia", "Albania", "Greece", "Croatia", "Malta")
EU <- subset(europe, NAME %in% EU)

#Generate one map per highlighted country

eucountries <- unique(europe$NAME)

for(i:length(eucountries))
    {
      print(i)
      png(paste(i,".png",sep=""), 200, 200)
      map("world", ylim=c(35,70), xlim=c(-20,45), col="#BFBFBF", fill=TRUE)
      plot(eucountries, add=TRUE, col="#769EB2", namesonly=TRUE)
      dev.off()
    }
```

I want to produce one png per country. Each png will have one specific country highlighted with a different color. The full map will be plotted each time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to vpipkt's comment that indicated that `map()$names` does provide a list of names of the things (polygons I suspect) that are plotted I could come up with a much more elgant solution:

- building an index of for those polygons that are named like countries
- using that information to build a color vector to color the countries
- *Note: the borders provided by the maps packae seem a litle outdated, e.g. Yugoslavia*

```
# library
library(maps)

# options
old <- par()$mar
par("mar"=c(0,0,0,0))
YLIM <- c(35,70)
XLIM <- c(-20,45)

# plotting
  for(country in c("Germany", "Ireland", "Spain", "Greece", "Denmark", "Yugoslavia") ) 
  {
    polygon_names <- map("world", ylim=YLIM, xlim=XLIM)$names
    index  <- grep(country, polygon_names)
    colvec <- rep("white", length(polygon_names))
    colvec[index] <- "red"
    png(paste0(country,".png"))
      map("world", ylim=YLIM, xlim=XLIM, col=colvec, fill=TRUE)
    dev.off()
  }

# resetting options
par("mar"=old)
```

[image]

Comment: Awesome! It's exactly what I was looking for.
Thank you very much :)

Comment: I do have a question, though.
What are those numbers in the first line of the loop? They are calling the countries that will be plotted, but they do not correspond to anything in the  shapefile, do they? If I only plot i in c(2) I get the USSR, whereas 2 corresponds to Algeria in the shapefile...

Comment: Note the answer does not reference your GIS shapefile at all. The answer uses `library(maps)`. The numbers reference polygons in the library's binary file. See `map('world',ylim=c(35,70), xlim=c(-20,45), plot = FALSE)$names` for a reference of the names.

Comment: The numbers refer to the ordering of the data and are used to create a vector of colors (have a look at the `colvec` object) that is red for one of the plotted things and white for (hopefully) all others.

Comment: Thanks! It's way easier to use the actual country names rather than reference numbers :)
Now I'll just need to find out how to use an updated map (USSR, seriously?) like 'wrld_simpl' of the 'maptools' package. Getting close to what I need. Will post the code if I figure it out!

Comment: I am looking forward to this. The basic idea still should hold: Use a vector of colors to define which polygons should be highlighted and which not.

Comment: Found it! I slightly modified the "# plotting" section:
`bckgrd <- wrld_simpl$NAME
for(country in c("Denmark", "Faroe Islands", "Iceland", "Norway", "Russia", "Sweden", "United Kingdom") ) 
{
  colvec <- rep("#BFBFBF", length(bckgrd)) #color for all countries (grey)
  colvec[which(bckgrd ==country)] <- "#769EB2" #color for countries of interest (blue)
  png(paste0(country,".png"))
  plot(wrld_simpl, ylim=YLIM, xlim=XLIM, col=colvec, fill=TRUE)
  dev.off()
}`

Answer (score 0):

Inside your loop, try

```
plot(eucountries[i], add=TRUE, col="#769EB2", namesonly=TRUE)
```

in place of your current `plot` call. Note the subset of `eucountries`.

Comment: It didn't work (unexpected error in i), but petermeissner's answer did the trick :)